# Aggregate hits and sessions data from Analytics query in BigQuery

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

In Google Analytics BigQuery, the following query tries to aggregate information both at the `sessions` and at the `hits` level

```
SELECT
  visitId,
  trafficSource.source as source,
  trafficSource.medium as medium,
  device.browser as browser,
  min(hits.hour) as firstHitHour,
  boolean(count(hits.eventInfo.eventCategory = "SomeValue")) as hasSomeValue
FROM
  [my-table.ga_sessions_20150216]
GROUP BY
  visitId, source, medium, browser;
```

The line `boolean(count(hits.eventInfo.eventCategory = "SomeValue")) as hasSomeValue` is intended to be `true` if, among all the hits of a row's session, at least one hit has the `hits.eventInfo.eventCategory` equal to `SomeValue`.

The expected results look like:

```
sessionId   source         medium      browser      firstHitHour     hasSomeValue
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12318       google         cpc         firefox      12               true
13317       google         organic     safari       14               null
13551       bing           organic     firefox      14               true
13610       orange         display     chrome       14               true
14381       stackoverflow  referral    safari       15               false
14422       google         organic     chrome       15               true
```

However, the line mentioned above doesn't seem to work. Even if I put some dumb value, for instance `hits.eventInfo.eventCategory = "Blablablabla"`, it will output `true` for some rows anyway (whereas obviously no hit has this dumb value).

Actually, the instruction `count(hits.eventInfo.eventCategory = "Blablablabla")` - without the `boolean()` returns seemingly random results (have nothing in common with the actual counts).

What should this line be to trigger the correct output?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have an easier time using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/). To check for presence of the value within `hits`, use an `EXISTS` clause over it. For example,

```
SELECT
  visitId,
  trafficSource.source as source,
  trafficSource.medium as medium,
  device.browser as browser,
  (SELECT MIN(hour) FROM UNNEST(hits)) as firstHitHour,
  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE eventInfo.eventCategory = "SomeValue") as hasSomeValue
FROM
  `my-table.ga_sessions_20150216`
GROUP BY
  visitId, source, medium, browser;
```

See also the guide on [migrating from legacy to standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/).

If you do want to stick with legacy SQL, you will need to use `WITHIN RECORD` in conjunction with the count over `hits`.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't realize I had to uncheck the Legacy SQL box - now I have the `UNNEST expression references column hits which is neither grouped nor aggregated at` error from `UNNEST(hits)`

Comment: See related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40792981/unnest-expression-references-column-which-is-neither-grouped-nor-aggregated

Answer (score 1):

First, the problem of using `boolean(count(hits.eventInfo.eventCategory = "SomeValue"))` is that it will return `true` if hits.eventInfo.eventCategory has any non-NULL value (either "SomeValue" or another different) and it only will return `false` when all values of hits.eventInfo.eventCategory are null. But this is not an unexpected result:

1. Using `hits.eventInfo.eventCategory = "SomeValue"`, BQ assigns `true` or `false` according to the condition as expected to each hit with a non-NULL value and `null` if that hit has the `null` value.
2. However, since `count` "*Returns the total number of non-NULL values in the scope of the function*", using `count(hits.eventInfo.eventCategory = "SomeValue")` (grouping by visitId) BQ returns the aggregated number of `true` AND `false` obtained before, and only returns 0 if all hits were `null` for a given visitId. In other words, it counts all the non-null values, not only those satisfying the condition, so the problem of your query is here.
3. `boolean(...)` works as expected: returning true if the last expression is not 0 and not NULL, false if it is 0 and NULL if it is NULL (you won't obtain any null).

Second, as you said in your last comment, you can use `some()` instead of `boolean(count())`, but note that using it you will not obtain any `null` result, as you initially wanted in the provided example. You will obtain `true` if there is at least one hits.eventInfo.eventCategory equal to "SomeValue" and `false` otherwise. If this is ok for you, I think that this is the best option.

However, if you want to obtain `null` when all hits of the session have null hits.eventInfo.eventCategory, you could use:

```
SELECT
      visitId,
      trafficSource.source as source,
      trafficSource.medium as medium,
      device.browser as browser,
      min(hits.hour) as firstHitHour,
      boolean(MAX(              
               CASE WHEN hits.eventInfo.eventCategory = "SomeValue" THEN 1
                    WHEN hits.eventInfo.eventCategory != "SomeValue" THEN 0
                    ELSE null END
             )
         ) as hasSomeValue
FROM
  [my-table.ga_sessions_20150216]
GROUP BY
   visitId, source, medium, browser
```

First, to each hit we assign 1 if the condition is satisfied, 0 if it is not and null if the value is null. Second, by asking for the `max()`, we'll get 1 if there is at least one "SomeValue", 0 if there are non-null values but all of them are different from "SomeValue", and null if all hits have null-values for `hits.eventInfo.eventCategory`. Finally, we use `boolean()` to get `true`, `false` or `null`, depending on each case.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of outputting the desired result, by using `some()` instead of `boolean(count())`

```
SELECT
  visitId,
  trafficSource.source as source,
  trafficSource.medium as medium,
  device.browser as browser,
  min(hits.hour) as firstHitHour,
  some(hits.eventInfo.eventCategory = "SomeValue") as hasSomeValue
FROM
  [my-table.ga_sessions_20150216]
GROUP BY
  visitId, source, medium, browser;
```

I'm not really sure why `boolean(count())` triggered unexpected results, however.

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  visitId, source, medium, browser,
  MIN(hour) AS firstHitHour,
  LOGICAL_OR(hasValue) AS hasValue
FROM (
  SELECT
    visitId,
    trafficSource.source AS source,
    trafficSource.medium AS medium,
    device.browser AS browser,
    h.hour AS hour,
    EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE eventInfo.eventCategory = "SomeValue") AS hasValue
  FROM
   `my-table.ga_sessions_20161122`, UNNEST(hits) AS h
)
GROUP BY
visitId, source, medium, browser;
```