# UNNEST expression references column which is neither grouped nor aggregated

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery, unnest

Google Analytics BigQuery tables are structured like this (Legacy SQL notations - only relevant fields are shown):

```
visitId:                      INTEGER
hits:                         RECORD/REPEATED
hits.hour:                    INTEGER
```

On one such table, the following query works well:

```
SELECT
  visitId,
  MIN(h.hour) AS firstHitHour
FROM
  `my-table.ga_sessions_20161122`, UNNEST(hits) AS h
GROUP BY
  visitId
```

But using this alternative syntax:

```
SELECT
  visitId,
  (SELECT MIN(hour) FROM UNNEST(hits)) as firstHitHour
FROM
  `my-table.ga_sessions_20161122`
GROUP BY
  visitId
```

Triggers the following error:

> **Error**: UNNEST expression references column hits which is neither grouped nor aggregated

I understand that `UNNEST(hits)` must be somehow grouped or aggregated, but since this column is an `array (repeated)`, what does it mean exactly?

If I try to "group the column `hits`", as requested, like this:

```
(SELECT MIN(hour) FROM UNNEST(hits) as h GROUP BY h) as firstHitHour
```

Then I get a `Grouping by expressions of type STRUCT is not allowed` error.

How can this alternative syntax be corrected to produce the same result as the first one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My first Answer is for original version of this question.
When I answered, I realized you have changed it to quite different one :o)

So below answer is for most recent version of your question:

I think that in "alternative" version you just do not need GROUP BY at all, because you operate on original (un-flattened) row by row and for each row (visitId) you calculate firstHitHour

```
SELECT
  visitId,
  (SELECT MIN(hour) FROM UNNEST(hits)) as firstHitHour
FROM
  `my-table.ga_sessions_20161122`
```

In your initial query - you kind of flattening all records for each row - so that's why you need then to group them back

Answer (score 5):

Try below (it uses example from your original question):

```
SELECT
  visitId, source, medium, browser,
  MIN(hour) AS firstHitHour,
  LOGICAL_OR(hasValue) AS hasValue
FROM (
  SELECT
    visitId,
    trafficSource.source AS source,
    trafficSource.medium AS medium,
    device.browser AS browser,
    h.hour AS hour,
    EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE eventInfo.eventCategory = "SomeValue") AS hasValue
  FROM
   `my-table.ga_sessions_20161122`, UNNEST(hits) AS h
)
GROUP BY
visitId, source, medium, browser;
```